# Virtual Machine for Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013

I would install sp 2013 tonight, however as long time ago I havent used VMs on my pc I wanted to know which vm software should I install, I have windows 7 and I suppose hyper v wont run or even install.

I suppose Virtual Server? VM Ware? which is best?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Virtual Server doesn't support X64 guests.

So running Win 7 your best options are most likely:

- [VHD Boot](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2009/04/07/windows-7-vhd-boot-setup-guideline.aspx)
- VM Ware

VM Ware is nice because you may have other things running on the machine at the same time, but be aware of the [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013 Preview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28office.15%29.aspx), which states 8GB Ram for foundation, 24GB for Server, so unless you have a lot of RAM VHD boot may be the best option

Comment: I suppose I do this but with the windows 2012 media instead of win 7?

Comment: Yes the vhd should use Server 2012 or 2008 R2, the link was just the first I could find about the setup process

Answer (score 8):

Another option would be to use VirtualBox by Oracle which supports 64 bit guests and is free.

Comment: I am trying it on Windows server 2012, but getting network adapter problem, dunno if its just me :/

Comment: looks like there is a bug with virtualbox and server 2012 in that the guest additions don't work. I had the same issue and went with 2008R2.

Answer (score 4):

Because you've to create x64 boxes, you can only use

- VirtualBox
- VMWare

on Windows 7. For creating a SharePoint 2013 dev environment the following setup works fine

- separated Domain Controller

  - Windows Server 2012 RC
  - 1 GB of RAM
- SharePoint development Box

  - Windows Server 2012 RC
  - 10 GB of RAM

while doing SharePoint development on my HP EliteBook w/ 16 gigs of RAM, 5 gigs are enough for my daily outlook, lync and internet stuff..

Answer (score 2):

I have created a 2013 VM and uploaded it to the cloud. If you'd like to, you can get the download and other VM details from my wordpress blog at: http://gauravmahajan.net/2012/07/22/sharepoint-2013-virtual-machine/
Hope you find it useful!
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

If this helps at all, I have listed about 20 different concepts or ways to create a [SharePoint 2013 development environment](http://www.matthewjbailey.com/sharepoint-2013-dev-environment/)

Answer (score 0):

I had Sun Virtual Box for last one year in the windows 7  for sharepoint 2010. It helps you in alerting if some hardware requirements are not good to go further in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

We've got Hyper-v Vm's running a SharePoint setup and it works OK.