# Installing Sharepoint 2013 Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, 2013

How can I install Sharepoint 2013 on Windows 7? (without virtual machine)

I'm dev and I don't have money for a windows server system!!

Answer (score 6):

From [How to: Set up an on-premises development environment for apps for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/fp179923%28v=office.15%29)

Installation of SharePoint 2013 Preview is supported only on Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2 x64 or Windows Server 2008 R2. If you want to develop apps for SharePoint for SharePoint 2013 Preview on Windows 7, you can sign up for an Office 365 Developer Site and develop apps remotely. See [How to: Set up an environment for developing apps for SharePoint on Office 365](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/fp161179%28v=office.15%29) for the instructions to create this kind of development environment.

Comment: How come that Microsoft keeps punishing developers that want to study their technology at home ? :(
I also don't have the money to spend on all this infrastructure.

Answer (score 3):

As I suggested in answer to [Virtual Machine for Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41136/virtual-machine-for-sharepoint-2013) one option is to use [VHD Boot](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2009/04/07/windows-7-vhd-boot-setup-guideline.aspx) as the [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013 Preview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28office.15%29.aspx) are pretty high.

Currently you can use [Windows Server 2012 Release Candidate (RC)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh670538.aspx) for free.

Comment: +1 for the boot to VHD advise. Very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Now you can install on windows 7/8, you decide if it's a good fit for you :-) Of course ABSOLUTELY COMPLETELY unsupported but IMHO it works great for a dev environment.

http://www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inl%C3%A4gg/6/Install-SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-7-8-8-1

Thanks,
Jonas

Comment: I'm getting the error ,Setup can’t find or validate an installation file. Please try reinstalling Office from your installation source, or if you installed from a downloaded package, please re-download and reinstall. If you continue to have problems, please contact Microsoft or your system administrator.

Answer (score 2):

I've been doing SharePoint 2013 Dev for a few weeks now remotely from Windows 7 on a Server 2008 R2 VM.

You ABSOLUTELY need at least a BARE MINIMUM of 8GB of RAM to run SP2013.  You can probably get away with 4GB if you completely disable search and/or run SQL on a different server.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get a trial of Windows Server 2008 R2 for free which lasts for 6 months.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/2008-r2-trial.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have installed windows server 2008 RC2
I tried to modify the config.xml but I consegido running on Windows 7
[enter link description here](http://alduar.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/instalar-sharepoint-2013.html)

Aldo Flores
@alduar

Comment: Thanks for the link to your own blog - love the name ;-). Please note that we  require relevant answers and disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck. Unlike SP 2010, you cannot install SP 2013 on Windows 7 or any other client OS.

Your best options are:

- Since Windows 8 supports Hyper-V, you can run SP 2013 as a VM on Windows 8.

  Check out this video: [Setting up team development infrastructure for SharePoint 2013 development](http://www.bing.com/videos/watch/video/setting-up-team-development-infrastructure-for-sharepoint-2013-development/10tcd4al4)
- Create a cloud hosted environment. [CloudShare](http://go.cloudshare.com/SharePoint2013_Website-Banner.html) now offers SP 2013 beta environments.

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT absolutely need 8GB to run SP2013.  I've got a Single Server running all services including SQL 2012 on 6GB Ram, it's a bit slow but it works fine.

This blog from Bamboo has good instructions to install SP2013 on a Windows 7 PC, though I haven't tried them yet.

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2014/08/21/guest-blog-by-jonas-nilsson-install-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-7-8-8-1.aspx