# Starting a SharePoint Site with Visual Studio on Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, office-365

I have been developing a site with SharePoint Designer and a web browser for awhile and I would like to start customizing the site with Visual Studio. I exported a .wsp file for the site and tried to import it into Visual Studio but I got the following error:

[image]

I tried installing both of these programs on Windows 7 and they don't seem to be compatible. Is there really no way for Visual Studio to handle this in Windows 7? It seems really counter-intuitive that I should need to purchase and install a server operating system to do something I was doing ten minutes ago mostly *in browser*.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Really hoping that MS hasn't let me down because I really don't have a way to get a server OS. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to develop SharePoint solutions (farm or sandboxed), you must have SharePoint server installed.  You can develop SharePoint apps without SharePoint Server, but you may need the [Office Developer Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/03/03/announcing-office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2013-march-2014-update.aspx), depending on your version of Visual Studio (the latest version of 2013 *may* have them installed already).
SharePoint 2013 does not support Windows 7/8/8.1.  You can find [workarounds](http://www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inl%C3%A4gg/6/Install-SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-7-8-8-1) to allow you to install, however it is not supported by Microsoft, and should only be used in development environments.
On a side note, you can sometimes find developer/preview licenses (good for 180 days) for Microsoft Products in their [Test Lab Guides](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1262.test-lab-guides.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Not, for do work in SharePoint from Visual Studio is required have install SharePoint (2010, 2013) in you local machine.

For know how to install SharePoint in Windows 7/8 read this:

[Installing Sharepoint 2013 Windows 7](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41204/installing-sharepoint-2013-windows-7)